# Jest/Enzyme unit testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following function which needs to be tested.

```
    export function buildOptions(options) { 
        var oList=[];   
        for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
            oList.push (
              <option key={"optId"+i} value={options[i]["id"]}>
                  {options[i]["name"]}
              </option>
            )
         }    
         return oList;
      }
```

I have a testcase as follows

```js
it ('should return an array containing the populated options', () => {
    let teams = [{"name":"A","id":1},{"name":"B","id":2}]

     expect(JSON.stringify(Helper.buildOptions(teams))).toMatch(
         JSON.stringify([<option value={1}>A</option>, <option value={2}>B</option>])
      );

});
```

I am getting an error **as the keys** **differ** between the expected and received response. Could you please let me know how to get over the error/mock the keys?

Expected value to match:

```
"[{\"type\":\"option\",\"key\":null,\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"value\":1,\"children\":\"A\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}},{\"type\":\"option\",\"key\":null,\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"value\":2,\"children\":\"B\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}]"
```

Received:

```
"[{\"type\":\"option\",\"key\":\"optId1\",\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"value\":1,\"children\":\"A\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}},{\"type\":\"option\",\"key\":\"optId2\",\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"value\":2,\"children\":\"B\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}]"
```

Comment: From looking at your data it seems like the mistake is actually in what you expect. You are expecting a key of null while in your function you assign the key optId1, so there is the mismatch. Your "expected" value should probably also contain the keys to match the actual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your option is missing the `key` value hence it is not matched. Maybe try this:

```
  it ('should return an array containing the populated options', () => {
      const teams = [
        { "name": "A", "id": 1 },
        { "name": "B", "id": 2 }
      ];
      const EXPECTED_OUTPUT = JSON.stringify([
        <option key="optId1" value={1}>A</option>,
        <option key="optId2" value={2}>B</option>
      ]);

      expect(JSON.stringify(Helper.buildOptions(teams))).toMatch(EXPECTED_OUTPUT);
  });
```

**Update**

There are many ways to test it, if you want to check the length of the result you can use `.toHaveLength()`, something like below:

```
it('should return an array containing the populated options', () => {
  const teams = [
    { "name": "A", "id": 1 },
    { "name": "B", "id": 2 }
  ];
  const result = Helper.buildOptions(teams);

  // Check if option exist and have length of 2
  expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  expect(result).toHaveLength(2);

  // Check if the options is as expected
  expect(result[0]).toEqual(<option key="optId1" value={1}>A</option>);
  expect(result[1]).toEqual(<option key="optId2" value={2}>B</option>);
});
```

More documentation about Jest testing - expect: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Comment: For a more general case , how to modify the test if I want to check whether output contains any particular element? For example in this case, if I need to check if the option exists and check its length?